# Smudging of colors in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, illustration, illustrator-effects

Is there any method to smudge colors in Adobe illustrator?

Comment: Yes kind of.  There's no smudge tool in Illustrator, but you could perhaps use [the Gradient Mesh tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/user-guide.html/illustrator/using/meshes.ug.html).

Comment: Thanks Billy,but is there any other tool or effect other than this?

Comment: No vectors dont work like pixels do.

Comment: In Illustrator CC 2019, there's a also a new [Freeform Gradient tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/freeform-gradients.html). You might want to take a look at that. Other than that, there are blur effects, but absolutely nothing like a smudge tool.  Illustrator is a vector application, and is nothing like raster based painting/image editing software.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you struggling? Questions should reflect the effort you've gone to yourself to try and answer it yourself.

Comment: The ultimate problem of a vector sortware is that at the end of the day they are limited with the features of the standard renderers. You gain the benefit of vectors only if the rendering can be done on the recieving end. Otherwise 3D graphics engines would be at par with vector software. So this limits what you can do.